# Website downloads a file that is not evan on my server

Tags: server, 20.04, nginx

When I goto my website https://sturtz.ml it tries to download a file that is not on my server. I am using Ubuntu Server 20.04 and Nginx. I will give any information requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to install the php file for apache2,